# Implementation of the weighted sum model without knowing the weights

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, sensitivity-analysis

I am looking to combine n metrics to obtain 1 single unified metric. For example, let's say I have 2 metrics n1 and n2 for k elements. I am particularly interested in the one or two elements that have the maximum metric. It so happens that maximum of n1 gives a different set of elements than maximum of n2.

I tried to use the basic weighted sum model as

combined metric = w1*n1 + w2*n2

The challenge is that I don't know about the nature of weights ( w1>w2 or otherwise)

**Is there any method to determine weights ? - all I know is n1, n2 for all k elements**

Hence, I carried out 3 separate cases :

1) Assuming w1 is dominant, I randomly generated 1000 values of both w1, w2 such that w1>w2 and w1+w2=1

2) I generated 1000 values of w1,w2 assuming w2 is dominant (w2>w1 & w1+w2=1)

3) I generated w1,w2 without any condition other than w1+w2 =1

For each of the above cases, I have 1000 simulations and I get 2 elements ( from k elements )corresponding to maximum combined metric for each simulation.so I have 2000 elements for 1000 simulations. Now I check the frequency of each element and finally filter out 2 elements that have the highest frequency in the lot of 2000 elements.

I get a different set of 2 elements for the three case mentioned above, I am stuck here on how to proceed further or make sense of this

All I am trying to do is get the best out of the n metrics by combining them using a weighted sum model ( weights unknown!)

I have a few other questions in which I need help -

1) As the weights are unknown , is it justifiable to randomly create weights like I have done and combine them

2) Are there other methods available to handle this kind of a problem ?

3) Is there a probabilistic framework that assigns a probability measure to each element based on all the available metrics

All my metrics are normalized between [0,1]

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to better define what you're trying to accomplish by combining these metrics. As you have seen, there are an infinite number of ways to combine n1 and n2 to get a unified metric. None of them are intrinsically "better" than any other. Do you want elements that do well in any score? Elements that do well in all scores? Elements that do well in one score, and not badly in the other? This needs to be defined first and foremost.

Comment: n1 and n2 are different metrics to predict failure of an element( small part in a structure). Higher the metric, higher the failure probability. It has been observed using experimental data that in some cases n1 alone gives a good prediction but n2 doesn't, in other cases n2 does best and in few cases, both don't do a good job. 

Hence my idea is to combine them in order that it gives a better prediction than using a single metric.

Comment: It sounds like you may not want a weighted combination of n1 and n2, but some kind of switching logic. In most cases you should just use n1. If you know the cases where n1 is no good, switch to n2 (maybe very low n1 is associated with bad prediction, or something like that). In cases where both and n1 and n2 are bad, combining them won't help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get "the best" out of the n metrics. Once you define "best", you'll have your answer. If you can't precisely define "best", you won't be able to weight your metrics to achieve "the best".

In other words, you're going to need to define a target and get target data, which you can then use to optimize your weights. You probably have a vague idea of what "best" means, but as you're finding out you can't do statistics/math/optimization with ideas: you need specifics.